# Generalizing a function for all particles in a system

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics

For my current research I had to derive a function that explains the force on one electron from another electron at the origin in a relativistic frame. The equation I got is shown here.

[image]

I'm not wondering if this equation is correct or not, but I have plugged in limits for cases where the second electron is on the x, y and z-axis and the result matches exactly what SR says it should.

Rather, I'm trying to generalize this equation so that it shows the force felt between any two electrons in the relativistic frame, regardless if one is positioned at the origin or not. This was my initial guess:

[image]

I know from my physics courses that when you want to generalize the normal Coulomb force you use the difference vector that I wrote in this new equation. Can I simply do the same thing with the polar angle theta? In this case theta is the angle between the z-axis and the particle in the CW direction. If someone could maybe tell me, is this the correct way to generalize an expression such as this? And if not do you have any good sources that could point me in the right direction? Also just to clarify, from my notation this new equation would be showing the force on particle 1, by particle 2.

Thanks

Comment: Do you assume that the direction of motion is along the polar axis?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that. The rest frame of the particles S' is moving in the positive z-direction relative to the lab frame S and all of the axes are aligned.

Comment: Wait, then what is $\theta$?

Comment: θ is the angle from the z-axis to any given particle in the frame. So for example if a particle was lying on the y' axis in the S' frame then θ would be 90° but the whole coordinate frame is still moving upwards in the z direction relative to S.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose two particles are at the spherical coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$. First we convert into Cartesian coordinates:

$$x_1 = r_1\sin{\theta_1}\cos{\phi_1}$$
$$y_1 = r_1\sin{\theta_1}\sin{\phi_1}$$
$$z_1 = r_1\cos{\theta_1}$$

and likewise for particle 2. To transform your formula, we need two quantities:

- $r$, the distance between the two points, and
- $\theta$, the angle between the vector connecting the two points and the $z$-axis.

The distance between two Cartesian points is

$$r = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$

which, when we substitute in our spherical coordinates and do a bit of algebra, becomes

$$r = \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos{(\theta_1-\theta_2)}\cos{(\phi_1-\phi_2)}}$$

The vector between the two points is

$$\vec{r} = (x_2 - x_1,y_2 - y_1,z_2 - z_1)$$

And the angle can be found using

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\vec{r}\cdot\hat{z}}{|\vec{r}||\hat{z}|}\right) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z_2-z_1}{r}\right)$$

which, after the same substitution, becomes

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r_2\cos{\theta_2}-r_1\cos{\theta_1}}{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos{(\theta_1-\theta_2)}\cos{(\phi_1-\phi_2)}}}\right)$$

Substituting these expressions in for $r$ and $\theta$ in your original formula should give you the correct expression.